# locate / use a vector based off one its elements

Tags: c++, vector

**VC++ 2010**

Lets say I have the following:

```
struct person {
    char *  name;
    int     age;
};
```

Then I have a vector which holds these:

```
std::vector <person> person_list;
```

Now, after pushing back a few of these elements, how can I locate one based off of one of its properties? Best case scenario, I would like it to return a pointer to the vectors element `'where name = string'` type of deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion to improve. Use `std::string` instead of `char*`.   You have to `#include <string>` for that.

- In C++11 you can use lamda and `std::find_if` as:

  ```
  #include <algorithm>

  auto it = std::find_if(persons.begin(), persons.end(), [](const person & p)
                              {
                                   return p.name = "string"; 
                              });
  ```
- In C++03, you can use functor as predicate:

  ```
  #include <algorithm>

  struct name_predicate
  {
      std::string name;
      name_predicate(std::string const & name) : name(name) {}
      bool operator()(person const & p) { return name == p.name; }
  };

  std::vector<person>::iterator it = std::find_if(persons.begin(), 
                                                  persons.end(),
                                                  name_predicate("string"));
  ```

Comment: I'm stuck with vc2010, should have mentioned that.

Comment: because it seems I am missing std::find. Is this only available in the 2011's STL?

Comment: @Headspin: No. `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: Ah! Thought it was included in <vector>. Should have checked that. Lets see if I can get this working now

Answer (score 2):

(Please use `std::string` instead of `char*` to avoid leaking or dangling pointers.)

You could use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) to get an iterator to that element:

```
#include <algorithm>   // allow us to use  std::find_if

struct NameFinder
{
    std::string target;
    bool operator()(const person& pers) const
    {
        return pers.name == target;
    }
};

...

NameFinder finder;
finder.target = "whatever name you want";

std::vector<person>::iterator it = 
                std::find_if(person_list.begin(), person_list.end(), finder);

std::cout << "name = " << it->name << "; age = " << it->age << std::endl;
```

The NameFinder here is a function object, which checks if a person's name matches a given target.

Comment: forgot to mention I am stuck with vc++2010

Comment: @Headspin: This is C++03, so VC++2010 will definitely work. Actually, VC++2010 already supports lambda function, so Nawaz's solution also works.

Comment: Any idea why I would be getting `Error: namespace "std" has no member "find_if"` ?

Comment: @Headspin: `#include <algorithm>`

Answer (score 1):

The stdlib uses iterators instead of pointers. In the `algorithm` header you will find the function templates `find` and `find_if`. The first searches for an element by value identity and the second by a predicate and returns an `iterator` to the first match. You can either add an overload for `operator==` to your person class and use the first version or write a predicate and go with the second.

Here is an example predicate:

```
struct person_equal {
  bool operator()(const person& p, const char* name) {
    return strcmp(p.name, name);
  }
};
```

Note that it uses the C-function `strcmp`. You should store `std::stringS` in your `person` objects instead of `char*`.

Now, this predicated takes two elements, but `find_if` expects an unary predicate. You need to `bind` the second parameter to some fixed value. Here I use the deprecated `bind2nd`. You should either use `boost:::bind` or a C++ TR1 replacement.

```
std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind2nd(person_equal(), "foobar"));
```

In C++0x you would use a lambda:

```
std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const person& p) { return strcmp(p.name, "foobar"); });
```

Or you can just iterate:

```
std::vector<person>::iterator my_find(std::vector<person>& v) {
  for(std::vector<person>::iterator it = v.begin(), it != v.end(), ++it) {
    if(strcmp(it->name, "foobar")) return it;
  }
}
```